# The screen doesn't get updated but get console log when database get updated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am building backend app, when the order is placed I get console log but the screen doesn't get updated and also the back button(react navigation), response after few seconds.

```
  const GetdataUsers = async () => {
    let grabbedData1 = [];
          let customerList1 = [];
          await firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`/serviceProvider/${user1.uid}/franchise/customers`)
            .orderByKey()
            .on("value", (snapshot) => {
              customerList1.push(snapshot.val());
              // setCustomerList(customerList1);
              if (customerList1) {
                Object.keys(customerList1).map(function (key) {
                  let y = customerList1[key];
                   Object.keys(y).map(function (key2) {
                      let x = y[key2]; // get all customer id
                      // From that id fetch all the orders they have
                       firebase
                        .database()
                        .ref(`/orders/${x}`)
                        .orderByKey()
                        .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
                          grabbedData1.push(snapshot.val());
                          console.log("grabbedData1....",grabbedData1);
                          // Grab all orders from the customers and set it
                          setShowloading(false);
                          setOrders(grabbedData1);
                        });
                    })
                });
              }
            });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    GetdataUsers();
  }, []); // [orders] tried this way also
```

When placing orders in bracket as shown above back button freezes and doesn't get any update . Also tried returning the data from function and setorder inside useEffect but stuck in a loop.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want the code to accomplish? Are you trying to append any new `snapshot.val()` data to your `userData` state, or just the latest single value in an array? `grabbedData` is declared anytime `GetdataUsers` is called, so the conditional check is unnecessary.

Comment: I am try to get data in real-time as soon as someone place an order which can i see in terminal, but didn't get new value in the app.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more clear. I meant something more like "walking" us through your code, roughly line-by-line, explaining what each is accomplishing.

Comment: Sorry, I edit the code little bit, was my mistake.  At first query I  fetch all the customers Ids that they have which is "x" (let x = y[key2];) then another query for all orders that customer (x) have  and then store it to oders (setOrders(grabbedData1);)  and to print on the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first query I fetch all the customers Ids that they have which is
> "x" (`let x = y[key2];`) then another query for all orders that customer
> (x) have and then store it to orders (`setOrders(grabbedData1);`) and to
> print on the app

Issues I see with the code:

1. You care mutating arrays in the `getDataUsers` function.
2. You've a set of nested firebase subscriptions that *necessarily* depend on the just updated `customerList`.
3. You don't unsubscribe from any firebase snapshot subscriptions.

I think it would be better to split this into two separate actions, or effects, one to handle the user's `uid` changing to set the current `customerList` state, and a second to handle fetching/updating the orders state when the `customerList` state updates.

Example:

Update the customer list when user changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/serviceProvider/${user1.uid}/franchise/customers`)
    .orderByKey()
    .on("value", (snapshot) => {
      setCustomerList(snapshot.val());
    });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [user1.uid]);
```

Update the orders when customer list updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const innerSubscriptions = [];

  if (customerList) {
    setOrders([]); // <-- clear orders for new customers list
    Object.values(customerList).forEach((customer) => {
      Object.values(customer).forEach((id) => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/orders/${id}`)
          .orderByKey()
          .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
            const order = snapshot.val();
            // Grab all orders from the customers and merge
            setOrders((orders) => [...orders, order]);
          });
        innerSubscriptions.push(unsubscribe);
      });
    });
  }
  return () => {
    innerSubscriptions.forEach((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe());
  };
}, [customerList]);
```

Comment: Thanx sir, Its working I have changed setOrder([...orders, order]) because the list was repeating many times but when I click backbutton I get an  error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.val')"

Comment: @mgons Which `snapshot.val()` has the issue?

Comment: The first one in useEffect , setCustomerList(snapshot.val());

Comment: @mgons From firebase documentation I don't see a way for `snapshot` to be undefined, but if this is somehow occurring you can use an Optional Chaining operator to guard potential undefined/null accessed. Example: `setCustomerList(snapshot?.val());`.

Comment: Thanks :). Now this work starching head since. But I didn't understand it . Is is the short hand of "? :"

Comment: @mgons It (`?.`) is the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It's *roughly* shorthand for a null-check/guard-clause, i.e. `setCustomerList(snapshot && snapshot.val());`.

Comment: Thnks @Drew Reese

Answer (score -1):

You have made an async function but you haven't used the await keyword. Also you'll have to create a state for loader and conditionally render a loader component till you have fetched all the data.

Comment: Vscode suggest me to remove await, and the loader has its state. but still doesn't get update using await

Comment: can you paste the whole file? and await is needed, idk why vs code is asking to remove it.

Comment: I uploaded a page to https://github.com/mgonekar/temp , with screenshot